# WCF change endpoint address at runtime

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have my first WCF example working. I have the host on a website which have many bindings. Because of this, I have added this to my web.config.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

This is my default binding http://id.web, which works with the following code.

```
EchoServiceClient client = new EchoServiceClient();
litResponse.Text = client.SendEcho("Hello World");
client.Close();
```

I am now trying to set the endpoint address at runtime. Even though it is the same address of the above code.

```
EchoServiceClient client = new EchoServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://id.web/Services/EchoService.svc"); 

litResponse.Text = client.SendEcho("Hello World");
client.Close();
```

The error I get is:

```
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
```

Please suggest how I may change the endpoint address at runtime?

**Additional here is my client config, requested by Ladislav Mrnka**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEchoService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://id.web/Services/EchoService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEchoService" contract="IEchoService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IEchoService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/mikev-ws" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How does your client configuration look like?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I have updated my post to display the client config. thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So your endpoint address defined in your first example is incomplete. You must also define endpoint identity as shown in client configuration. In code you can try this:

```
EndpointIdentity spn = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/mikev-ws");
var address = new EndpointAddress("http://id.web/Services/EchoService.svc", spn);   
var client = new EchoServiceClient(address); 
litResponse.Text = client.SendEcho("Hello World"); 
client.Close();
```

**Actual working final version by valamas**

```
EndpointIdentity spn = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/mikev-ws");
Uri uri = new Uri("http://id.web/Services/EchoService.svc");
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri, spn);
var client = new EchoServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IEchoService", address);
client.SendEcho("Hello World");
client.Close();
```

Comment: I have modified my post displaying the code i used based on your sample and the error I am now getting. Thank you.

Comment: @Valamas: Are you sure that your didn't accidentally change some part of config only on one side of communication? What happens if you only call your initial code without passing EndpointAddress from code?

Comment: It is working now. the problem was the config change I added while working with John Petrak. Not helped by leaving that in when I left the office for an hour. Thank you very much for your help. Perfect, cheers :)

Comment: This did the trick for me. For others, like me who also need to pass credentials, you can add the following lines immediately after `client` is declared:

    `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUsername";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword";`

Answer (score 23):

This is a simple example of what I used for a recent test.
You need to make sure that your security settings are the same on the server and client.

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
var myEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://servername:8732/TestService/");
client = new ClientTest(myBinding, myEndpointAddress);
client.someCall();
```

Comment: In the web.config i changed to `<security mode="None">`. I have appended my current code and error to my original post.

Answer (score 16):

app.config

```xml
<client>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="LisansSoap" 
    contract="Lisans.LisansSoap" 
    name="LisansSoap" />
</client>
```

program

```
 Lisans.LisansSoapClient test = new LisansSoapClient("LisansSoap",
                         "http://webservis.uzmanevi.com/Lisans/Lisans.asmx");

 MessageBox.Show(test.LisansKontrol("","",""));
```

Comment: Much simpler this way. I'm using it for AD WS

Answer (score 9):

We store our URLs in a database and load them at runtime.

```
public class ServiceClientFactory<TChannel> : ClientBase<TChannel> where TChannel : class
{
    public TChannel Create(string url)
    {
        this.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url));
        return this.Channel;
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
var client = new ServiceClientFactory<yourServiceChannelInterface>().Create(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `EndpointAddress` and use an instance of the client to determine the binding

```
        EndpointAddress a = new("http://localhost:50415/Service1.svc");
        Service1Client c = new(new Service1Client().Endpoint.Binding, a);
        string result = c.GetData(3);
```

If you don't mind initializing the client twice