# How to consume a WCF with changing endpoint or server address

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am writing a .net application that will consume a service reference. The end point of the service reference will change, as it will be deployed on different servers.

Is it better to use reflection to consume the service reference at run time, or is it possible to to change the end point on the fly before I instantiate the object and use it?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151077/wcf-change-endpoint-address-at-runtime

Comment: Will having transformed config files suit your purpose

Comment: Thank you for pointing towards solution.